# How to typecast const class pointer to int* using c++ style typecasting

Tags: c++, casting

How to cast a const class pointer to int* in c++ style ?

Using only the 4 C++ static_cast, dynamic_cast, reinterpret_cast or const_cast

Consider the following class :

```py
class A
{
public:
    virtual void foo(A& a) { std::cout << "A::foo" << std::endl; }
};

void logPtr(int* c) { std::cout << std::hex << c << std::endl; }

const A* pa = new A();

logPtr((int*)pa);
```

How should the type cast in c++ style appear in this code ?

I expect an output of a hex number in the C style cast as well as C++ style typecast.

Comment: You didn't declare anywhere `pa`, which cast you are going to use is irrelevant. The compiler will fail before.

Comment: Why an `int*` and not a `void*`? Or a `std::uintptr_t`, if all you want is the value of the address?

Comment: By condition I have int* given and need to know how to typecast it

Comment: `logPtr(const_cast<int*>(reinterpret_cast<int const*>(pa)));`

Comment: @Shago Just to print a pointer, there's no cast (or `hex`) needed at all.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ except when the pointer is to a character type. (which is not the case here)

Comment: @eerorika Yes, that's an exception and we have well known dupes about that.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use `reinterpret_cast`, but allow me to [frame challenge](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6842/whats-a-frame-challenge): Don't use `int*` in the first place. `void*`'s a better choice. Any pointer type can be converted to `void*` without cast.

```
void logPtr(const void* p) { std::cout << std::hex << p << std::endl; }

const A* pa = new A();
logPtr(pa);
```

Don't coerce types when you don't have to.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` cannot cast away constness. Did you mean `const_cast`?